# How to get the current route ID within a View from the URL (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Within the view that is returned from a URL such as /Controller/Action/1 (assuming the default route of controller/action/id), how can I get access to the ID from within the View?

I don't want to have to add it to the ViewData dictionary at the action level when handling the request.

Comment: Why don't you want to add it to the ViewData dictionary? That is the mechanism that is provided for exactly what you are describing.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<%=Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]%>
```

Comment: +1 simple, effective and is exactly what the question asked for!

Comment: why isnt this properly documented anywhere else on web? grrrr

Comment: This answer doesn't adequately explain how it mitigates Reflected XSS. Downvoted.

Comment: @CervEd that's not part of the question but if it is important to you, the resultant string is escaped by the razor engine unless you override it. Also, the controller has protection against potentially dangerous route values.

Comment: @Francisco security is important to me and presumably also the users, please validate user input. I'm sorry but this answer is terrible and lot's of people are going to copy-paste this into production. Please consider taking it down. https://owasp.org/www-community/ASP-NET_Request_Validation All you're doing is relying on .NET to all possible kinds XSS validation for you. You're taking an integer from the Route. Do this in the controller. Validate that it's an integer. Don't do this

Comment: @CervEd the resulting output is html encoded, that's pretty secure. If you don't understand how razor views and/or the controller work please inform yourself before commenting again. How can you not rely on .net security if you're using that technology? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @francisco HTML encoding does not prevent XSS reflection, there are lots of ways to inject XSS https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet More are continuously being found. Use MVC like you're supposed to. Validate the input in the controller, don't trust user input

Comment: @CervEd you keep thinking this question is about displaying some value in the view. It's not. The security issue you're talking about is outside the scope of the question. Don't worry I'll make sure to put an OWASP link in every answer I make in the future.

Comment: @Francisco That's like telling someone that ask how to open a can with a gun, "aim it and shoot". It's an XY problem. Be a good sport and tell them it's a bad idea, or at the very least to aim it away from their feet. The question doesn't specifically state the value is to be rendered but come on man. It's a View. Most people that come here are trying to do that. This is the wrong approach. The entire point of MVC is to handle user input in the controller. It doesn't exactly help that the answer is in Web Forms and vulnerable to XSS

Answer (score 16):

ViewData is exactly the right way of doing this.

Your other option would be to pass a model that contains ID to the view.

**Edit:** Without knowing exactly what you're tying to do, it's tough to give more specific advise. Why do you need an ID, but not any other model data? Is your controller really only sending the Id field to the view? It's hard to imagine what the scenario is.

If the ID value is truly the only model information that is being passed to your view, then you could use the ID itself as the model.  Then the return value of your action method would be `View(id)` and you wouldn't need to use ViewData.

Comment: Unfortunately the View doesn't have a model.

Something about `ViewData["id"] = id;` just doesn't sit right with me. I guess it's the fact that I am using this pattern quite a few times. Once or twice and I probably wouldn't mind.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Adding it to the viewdata is the right thing to do. As for how to add it, you could always add a custom `ActionFilter` which grabs it from the route dictionary and pushes it into the viewdata.

Comment: I like that idea, with proper null value checking you would just put that at the top of your controller and you should be able to always rely on it being there when it's supposed to be.

Comment: Or just make a nice little ViewDataWrapper class that could manage the "what to do if this is null" stuff for ya . . .

Answer (score 3):

Simple Answer In Razor:

```
@Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

In ASP.NET Core

```
@Url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **.NET Core**

Use this code

```
Url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can pass `id` as **`Route Data` or `QueryString`**, so to **support both of them** i recommend this way:

```
var routeValues=Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
var paramName = "id";
var id = routeValues.ContainsKey(paramName)?
         routeValues[paramName]:
         Request.QueryString[paramName];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can direct use in url action 
Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]

Comment: This worked for me. In ASP.NET Core it's Url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["id"] in case anyone else is looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents, but I always use view models for passing any data to my views. Even if it's as simple as needing an `int` like the id.

Doing this makes accessing this value trivial, as MVC does all the work for you.

For what it's worth I typically [name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336665/2421277) my view models as such:

`{Controller}{ViewName}ViewModel`

This helps keeps things organized at scale.

An example:

```
// ~/ViewModels/HomeEditViewModel.cs
public class HomeEditViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

// ~/Controllers/HomeController.cs
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  return View(new HomeEditViewModel() { Id = id });
}

// ~/Views/Home/Edit.cshtml
@model HomeEditViewModel

<h1>Id: @Model.Id</h1>
```