# ASP.NET MVC View Model Naming Conventions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I know I will probably get a mixed opinion on this, but I was wondering if there were and "Best Practices" for model naming conventions.

I have a rather large application and I have adopted the following model naming convention:

- Models

  - Add

    - CategoryAddModel
    - ProductAddModel
  - Edit

    - CategoryEditModel
    - ProductEditModel
  - View

    - CategoryViewModel
    - ProductViewModel

I was thinking of the following as well:

- Models

  - Add

    - AddCategoryModel
    - AddProductModel
  - Edit

    - EditCategoryModel
    - EditProductModel
  - View

    - ViewCategoryModel
    - ViewProductModel

Which do you prefer, and why?

Do you think it really matters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't matter. You should name things in a consistent, logical, and straightforward way. Basically, just pick something that makes sense and makes you most productive. Consider how your naming convention would work with IntelliSense.

You might also want to consider how easy your code will be to maintain a year from now.

Comment: Your answer is ok, but it should be better if there is some "official" convention so developers all around world can use it.
Benefints are obvious. When someone joins project he doesn't have to learn new convention. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 18):

I prefer like `{ViewName}{Controller}ViewModel`. I also remove `Models` folder, instead I put view models in `ViewModels` folder. That makes more sense to me.

eg. `AddCategoryViewModel`

Comment: +1, doing the same about ViewModels folder. I just kept the Models folder for my "actual" models (ie the POCO ones, ORM related)

Comment: I like your answer, but what about if I have same ViewModel name but in different areas? what naming convention do you recommended?

Comment: -1, I'd do it the other way around `{Controller}{ViewName}ViewModel` since when you use Intellisense, typing `Add` would give too many results when you probably already know you're looking for a 'Category'. So `Category` would give `CategoryAdd`, `CategoryView` and `CategoryEdit` which is a much less extensive list. +1 for separate `Models` and `ViewModels` directory

Comment: Willy: You can have model with same name in different area, because area will be in different namespace.

Eg. MyApp.Web.ViewModels.AddCategoryViewModel
      MyApp.Web.Areas.Blog.ViewModels.AddCategoryViewModel

Answer (score 8):

To pull out [Hightmaston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/431967/highmastdon)'s comment into a formal answer for clarity.

A logical template to follow would be:

`{Controller}{ViewName}ViewModel`

This encourages better file organization at scale, and reduces the number of Intellisense "hits".

A simple example might be as follows:

`CategoryIndexViewModel`

For brevity you may also consider:

`CategoryIndexModel`

Comment: For larger projects as well, following a pattern of naming like this really helps remove the guess work on how to name new things or how to debug/find things.

Answer (score 1):

In theory CategoryViewModel, CategoryAddModel and CategoryEditModel will contain the same properties, so there is little point tripling the number of view models you have in your UI. Just CategoryModel should suffice. It's the type of HTTP requests being received by your controller which defines whether it's a GET or POST operation. The model used to populate a view for a GET, or capture form data for a POST will be the same type either way.

Comment: Old question I know, but wanted to point out that a perfectly valid reason for differentiating the action in the model name is when different actions require different validation logic or similar constraints. For example, you might be able to set all properties when adding an item, but maybe the update rule is that you can only update certain properties. In this scenario, it absolutely makes sense to have different models for different actions, rather than adding a ton of senseless conditional validation to the same model.