# ASP.NET Razor: Send variable as parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My view contains the following table definition:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Artist</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var album in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@album.Title</td>
            <td>
                @{
                    foreach (var artist in ViewBag.Artists)
                    {
                        if (artist.ArtistID == album.ArtistID)
                        { @artist.Name }
                    }
                }
            </td>

            <td>
                @{
                    foreach (var genre in ViewBag.Genres)
                    {
                        if (genre.GenreID == album.GenreID)
                        { @genre.Name }

                    }
                }
            </td>

            <td>@album.Price</td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Albums">Details </a>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Albums">Edit </a>
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="Albums">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

The `Details`, `Edit`, and `Delete` options in the final column need to be keyed to the `AlbumID` property of the `album` variable, in order to ensure that the redirect operates on the proper album. I had thought the parameter for this might be `asp-parameter`, much like the action is set by `asp-action`, but this does not appear to exist.

What is the proper method to pass a variable as a URL parameter (for instance, `/Albums/Details/var`), and what name is used to retrieve this on the other side?

Shyju's answer deals with passing the parameter; my attempts at retrieving the parameter thus far have been as follows:

`<%=Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]%>` - Fails to load, invalid character `<`.

`ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]` - Fails to load, cannot compare `int` and `object` using `==`.

`RouteData.Values["id"]` - Compilation error, name does not exist in current context.

Comment: Why dont you use the classic way? <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Albums", new { id = album.AlbumID })">Details</a>

Comment: Would `@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Albums", new { albumID = album.ID }, null)` work rather than using the asp-*` attributes?

Comment: Or the html helper?? @Html.ActionLink(....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using link tag helper, You can pass additional information to the action method using the `asp-route-[paramName]` attribute. For example, if you want to pass the album id to the `id` parameter of your details action method, you can do this

```
<a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Albums" asp-route-id="@album.ID">Details </a>
```

This will generate the markup like below

```
<a href='/Albums/Details/101'>Details</a>
```

Where `101` will be replaced by an actual Album Id value.

Assuming your Details action method has a parameter named `id`

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  // to do : Get the album using the id and send something to the view
}
```

Comment: This answers the first half of the question, but how is the parameter accessed on the destination view? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979532/how-to-get-the-current-route-id-within-a-view-from-the-url-asp-net-mvc) suggests the use of `<%=Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]%>` but that returns an error.

Comment: You need to use a parameter in your details action and the value will be available in that when you navigate via the link. See the updated answer.

Comment: Got the updated data by passing it in via ViewBag; passing the album with the given id as a model would have worked as well.